# Java string end with space

Tags: java, string

always meet problem with java string's last end of string sign. It seems it occupy a space, therefore it may be return different answers when do if string[a] == string[b], or even sometimes a.equals(b) still doesn't work even a and b seems the same but one of them contain a end sign. 
Wonder Which function can be used for the ignoring feature of the string?

Comment: You could try trimming the whitespace with `.trim()`

Comment: `String#trim`, `String#startsWith`...?

Comment: `string[a] == string[b]` don't do that

Comment: first trim the string then compare using equals , here == won't work

Comment: Why did you tag this with C++?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with C++'s string?

Comment: Rapprz I think C++ may count the same question so I tagged it. (I know now normally in C++ people always use char array instead of string)   @juanchopanza yes, I did have the same problem with C++ before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to remove surrounding whitespace and then use `String.equals()` (*not* `==`, See [15.21 Equality Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) in the Java Language Specification for full details.). Remember that `String` instances are immutable so `String.trim()` returns a new `String` and it is that which must be used in the `equals()` check.

Note that `trim()` removes leading whitespace also. If this is undesired then use `String.substring()` to erase the trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

should always `trim()` the string before compare.

Comment: why should we 'always' trim the string if comparing?

Comment: for any **meaningful** comparison, it would help reduce the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

```
trim()
```

will return your string without spaces in the start and ends.

Ex:

```
String s =" test ";
s =s.trim(); //will become "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use only `stringA.equals(stringB);` to remove white spaces use `.trim()`